# UICollectionView row numbers aren't right

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I'm using to display elements of an array, but as I scroll it, the row number from `indexPath` jumps around and does not display the right content. To debug, I simply have the cell displaying the row number:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CNArticleCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: ArticleCellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    // check if there's anything here
    if ([CNArticleManager shared].loadedArticles.count < 1)
        return cell;

    // get current article
    MWFeedItem* item = [[CNArticleManager shared].loadedArticles objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.item = item;
    cell.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}
```

This is what it's showing. The left got cut off a bit, but that's a 4, followed by a 1... I can't figure out why most of the cells are blank, or why the one's that show up are out of order, or (not displayed here) why some titles overlap each other.

[image]

Comment: Running into the same problem.  My indexPath is never the same when I click from cell to cell.  Did you ever figure this out?